# Exim 4 on Debian 8 - external mail does not accept

Tags: debian, exim, debian-jessie

A few days ago installed a new server: Debian 8, Exim4.

I can send mail from this server, I can receive mail internally but the server does not accept external mail.

All emails return with errors like

```
----- The following addresses had fatal errors -----
 Host not reachable.
```

I have CSF/LFD firewall installed and port 25 is open:
TCP_IN, TCP_OUT, TCP6_IN, TCP6_OUT.

**Exim configuration:**

```
internet site; mail is sent and received directly using SMTP

IP-addresses to listen on for incoming SMTP connections: 
127.0.0.1 ; ::1

Other destinations for which mail is accepted: 
example.com

Domains to relay mail for: 
example.com
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
IP-addresses to listen on for incoming SMTP connections: 
127.0.0.1 ; ::1
```

Your `exim` listen for incoming connections on the `localhost` only.

Comment: should i leave this empty?

Comment: Empty field means `every possible interface` so if you are not sure - leave it blank. In some more complicated environments you can explicitly assign an interface for listening